# Using python (urllib) to download a file, how to get the real filename?

Tags: python, url, authentication, download, urllib2

So I finally managed to get my script to login to a website and download a file... however, in some instances I will have a url like "http://www.test.com/index.php?act=Attach&type=post&id=3345".  Firefox finds the filename ok... so I should be able to.

I am unable to find the "Content-Disposition" header via something like remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']

Also, remotefile.geturl() returns the same url.

What am I missing?  How do I get the actual filename?  I would prefer using the built-in libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the task of the remote server/Service to provide the content-disposition header.

There is nothing you can do unless the remote server/service is under your own control..

Comment: If that is the case, how does firefox know what the name of the file is when I use "Save Link as"?  Is this a different type of request?  Can I simulate it?

Comment: Firefox has more context information like the link text to be used as fallback.

Comment: Ah, ok... it looks like that is what is happening on many of the files given through a text link, while thumbnail links for images were passing the content-disposition.  Too bad though... creates more work for me.

Comment: it is also possible that the browser deals with redirections although urllib2 should deal with redirections as well

Comment: Nah, doesn't appear to be a redirection... I ended up just parsing out the filename from the link's text if the Content-Disposition did not exist.  Thanks.